# "To give an idea": Different meanings

Tags: meaning, collocations

Can the collocation "to give an idea" be used in the sense of "to make a suggestion (that's worth considering)"? (For example: He gave me a million-dollar idea.)

Comment: It's not a collocation, but it's perfectly grammatical.  He gave you a puppy.  He gave you a million-dollar idea. He gave you a warning.  He gave you a headache. He gave you a stern look.  He gave you a cup of coffee. He gave you a chance. He gave you a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. This grammar is perfectly fine.